# Where to access the archives of philosophical journal "The human world"

Tags: anscombe

In the 70-s there must have been a journal called "The human world", for I have seen it in citations. However, it's a tricky word to google and I have found zero information about this journal online.

I am specially interested in Issue 9, November 1971. This issue contains comments from Bernard Williams and others on Elizabeth Anscombe's "Contraception and chastity", and also Anscombe's comments on their replies. Actually I did find the comments and replies in here: https://www.open.uwi.edu/sites/default/files/bnccde/PH19B/conchastity.html, however, portion of Anscombe's reply has been omitted for some reason. Mary Geach quotes from the omitted part in the introduction to the book "Faith in a hard ground", however, I would really like to read Anscombe's reply in its entirety, but it seems nowhere to be found.

Comment: Stanford University Library seems to have a physical copy of all issues....Brynmill is the publisher and seems to still exist. These are the two places you could contact I found so far. Issue 9 is Nov 1972 btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Human World* has been a journal published by Brynmill Press (a company still in existence) between 1970 and 1974.

Besides the mentioned interesting comments on Anscombe's *Contraception and Chastity* in issues 7 and 9 there is an interesting Essay by Wittgenstein in issue 3 as it seems.

As of getting hold of these issues, your best bet will be the corresponding [WorldCat entry](https://www.worldcat.org/title/human-world/oclc/1781465). There, you can enter your location and it will give you libraries within some hundred miles where it is available.